# Confusion between This and It

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I often get confused between 'This' and 'It' during sentence making, and because of that I face difficulties in sentence making. Few examples are given below-

1. It is the world's top choral events.
2. Have you seen it before?
3. It is enough.
4. It is impossible.
5. It is a boy

My confusion is here we can also use 'This' as well-

1. This is the world's top choral events.
2. Have you seen this before?
3. This is enough.
4. This is impossible.
5. This is a boy

Please give me some tips or tell me the proper use of 'this' and 'it'. Its very confusing.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between "it" and "this" is the presence of the object being spoken about. If the object is physically present before you, then "this" would be the suitable word to use here. If not, then "it" should be used. Keep in mind that if "it" is used in a sentence where the object being referred to is not mentioned, a sentence before it referring to it should be present.
So, to give an example of a situation:

You are at the movie theater and are inside the cinema when your friend asks you,
"Have you watched **this** before?"

You are in class and your friend says:
"I'm going to watch *insert movie title* tomorrow"
"Have you watched **it** before?"

Hope this helped.

Comment: While certainly true, note that "this" can indicate non-physical proximity as well.  For example, in the sentence `This is the day I've been waiting for`, it indicates a point in time rather than space, and in `Listen up because this is important` it indicates proximity in the conversation.